# Sort and remove duplicates using Python3

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to take a list of comma separated values, such as that shown below, and 1)sort the values in each individual line in ascending order and 2) remove duplicate values that remain within each individual line. My file is a .txt file and I am having troubles with set() due to the fact that my data is a str() and not int(). I have 5,836 lines that need sorting/duplicate removal.:

2,3,6,42,43,4,15,28,28,37,41,45

43,49

11,27,38,38

27,36

17,37

2,9,22,29,34,41,44

1,24,30

9,11,10,41

46,47,28,34

17,30,32,44

27,31

36,42,31,38,49

8,25

6,9,12,24,26,29,41,6,9,12,24,26,29,41

30,32,17

37,37

10,27,28,28

37,37,38,38

11,18

42,43,12

33,38,38

Comment: How much research have you done so far? Python has a documentation page of built-in functions including one for casting to int: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int Also, please include your code. There's only so much help someone can give without actually knowing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
liststr="2,3,6,42,43,4,15,28,28,37,41,45"
sorted(set([int(i) for i in liststr.split(',')]))
[2, 3, 4, 6, 15, 28, 37, 41, 42, 43, 45]

liststr="11,27,38,38"
sorted(set([int(i) for i in liststr.split(',')]))
[11, 27, 38]
```